# The term 'Add-AzureAccount' is not recognized

Tags: powershell, azure

I have install Windows azure powershell.

After that when i start as the **Windows azure powershell** as **administrator** i am getting an error ---

```
Saying  The term 'Add-AzureAccount' is not recognized
```

[image: ScreenShot]

How can i fix this error Anyone knows any solution !!

Comment: What version of azure PowerShell did you install? Have you tried closing PowerShell and reopening after you installed it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before running that cmdlet, can you try

```
Import-Module Azure
```

if the module is not found, you can try

```
Install-Module Azure
```

Be sure to run powershell as administrator for the latter.

Comment: When installing the Azure module, I get a warning that the repository is not trusted: ```PS Azure:\> Install-Module Azure

Untrusted repository
You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its InstallationPolicy value by running the Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install
the modules from 'PSGallery'?```

Comment: Just add -Force to the end